# Javascript and the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm in a spot of bother and my hairline is on the chopping block. When I integrated the maps API on this site, [ritaknoetze.com](http://ritaknoetze.com/contact/), everything worked perfectly.

However, copying that exact code for a different demo website, [scarabpaper](http://scarabpaper.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/contact-us), the map doesn't show up at all? Could someone show me the ropes on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code I got from Google itself that I modified for my WordPress theme/installation:

**JavaScript:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.009839, 22.78101);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 9,
              center: myLatlng,
              navigationControl: true,
              mapTypeControl: false,
              scaleControl: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var image = '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/assets/googlemaps_marker.png';
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.009839, 22.78101);
            var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
          }
        </script>
```

**My HTML where the javascript goes:**

```
<div class="contact_container">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
```

**My CSS for the affected divs**

```
#map_canvas {
    width: 880px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #dedcdc;}

.contact_container {    /*container for ALL the contact info*/
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dedcdc;
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;}
```

Any Help would be *greatly* appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never calling the `initialize()` method. It works if you call that method, even using a console.

Comment: you can attach an onload='javascript:initialize();' on the body

Comment: @kjy112: Should be `onload='initialize()'`

Comment: Thanks Matt, kjy and Felix for your keen eyes. Turns out my init event was hidden by an incorrect php function that only displays the init call on certain pages. Anyhooooo, I fixed it and everything is peachy again on the demo site - my hairline owes you ;)